# Keep cell color changed with checkbox on refresh

Tags: javascript, checkbox, colors

I have cells changing background color on checkbox check and I worked out how to keep the checkboxes checked on refresh (though looking back I don't think that works anymore), but I don't know how to keep the color change on refresh. I don't actually know Javascript at all and this is all from other questions but I want it to work. If I've done something completely wrong please correct me and don't assume I did it on purpose because I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".colourswitcher").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("td").css("background","#ff3333");  
    }else {
        $(this).closest("td").css("background","#202020");
    } 
});
});

$(function(){
var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
$('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to javascript, I'm going to ask the dumb question: Have you included jQuery?

This code that you've pulled makes use of jQuery, a very useful library (not built-in to javascript) that has become so commonplace that people often don't even state its name when asking or answering a question involving it. But anytime you see that $ notation, you're probably dealing with jQuery.

You need to include the library file in your html file so it knows what those special symbols and syntax are: 
    `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`

If you're testing this stuff in Google Chrome, press F12 and view the developer console. You will see "undefined" errors in red when you are missing things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer assuming you have a better working knowledge than my first answer:

The first bit of your code runs when the html document has loaded and attaches an event listener to change the nearest cell background color accordingly when the checkbox is clicked. Note two things here though. **1)** that behavior will be attached to all html elements with the class "colourswitcher", not just inputs. **2)** that behavior assumes that what was clicked has a property "checked", which only a checkbox does.

The middle bit I presume is supposed to run once, when the page is first loaded, to get the saved state of the checkbox from localStorage. This bit could be moved into the document ready bit.

The third bit of your code attaches an event listener to every input element (not just checkboxes) such that every time one is clicked, a checked true/false state will be saved in localStorage.

localStorage is a convenient way to save information between browser refreshes. You can save anything you want, ie. localStorage.CandyCanes = 7 and that variable will be stored in the user's browser and can be recalled later. Note that your above code will only work as intended if there's a single checkbox, because you're using one slot, or one variable, in localStorage to save: localStorage.input.

That's all I'm going to elaborate on this for now. If this is more than you expected, then it's time to hunker down and learn, or get a professional involved.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for not assuming I have any idea what I'm doing ^^ I think I did forget to include jQuery at that point... I've added it in anyway but I just gave up on that site all together and I'm using a spreadsheet instead. I'd still like to work out how to do it though and I'll probably try again later :) It was just experimentation for a personal project so it doesn't matter. Thanks for the help :)